# Django queryset subset with custom manager?

Tags: django, django-models, filter, subset, django-queryset

I have similar models:

```
class BaseInfo(models.Model):
  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  # other fields..
  class Meta:
     abstract = True

class Customer(BaseInfo):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   ## other fields..
```

In template I want to display a table of this model, but I want to highlight the inactive ones. So I have this fragment in template:

```
{% for c in customers %}
    <tr {%if not c.is_active %}class="not-active" {%endif%}>
      <td>..</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Now next to this I want to display the NUMBER of active ones.
I could do this in view:

```
all = Customer.objects.filter(name="foo")
excludeInactive = all.filter(is_active=False)
```

and then pass both in the context.
But I would prefer something like this in template:

```
{{customers.exclude_deleted.count}}
```

or maybe:
`{{customers.exclude_deleted|length}}` ?

I have more models which inherit this abstract class. So I think a manager on the base class could work? I just couldn't understand how to write one..
Also, what about performance? If I do two calls to `.filter()` will that result in two db queries, even though the second query is a subset of an already evaluated queryset?

Comment: Have a look at custom template tags

Comment: You might want to look into custom managers for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways. Some of them:

- Make all calculation in the view and pass to the context prepared data:

  ```
  customers = Customer.objects.filter(name="foo")
  active_customers_count = customers.filter(is_active=True)
  ```
- Custom template tag ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/)):

  tag

  ```
  from django import template

  register = template.Library()


  @register.assignment_tag
  def filter_qs(qs, **kwargs):
      return qs.filter(**kwargs)
  ```

  template

  ```
  {% filter_qs customers is_active=True as active_customers %}
  {{ active_customers|length }}
  ```
- Custom Manager with custom QuerySet ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager)):

  models

  ```
  class IsActiveQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
      def active(self):
          return self.filter(is_active=True)


  class IsActiveManager(models.Manager):
      def get_queryset(self):
          return IsActiveQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)


  class Customer(BaseInfo):
     objects = IsActiveManager()
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  ```

  template

  ```
  {{ customers.active|length }}
  ```

I would strongly recommend you to go with the first option, it will be the most "Pythonic" way.
Anyway django will make 2 separate sql queries for any of solution listed above.

Comment: In the manager solution, I might suggest changing to `active` to `inactive`.

Comment: Thank you @JaredGoguen, it was just a typo.

Comment: just to remind, I do want the inactive and active ones in the same table.. so if you override objects property, I wont be able to access the inactive ones?

Comment: by calling `Customer.objects.all()` you will get all (active, inactive) objects. But with `Customer.objects.all().filter(foo=bar).active()` you will get active objects. Basically we just apply extra filter, but incapsulated it in the queryset method.

Comment: And performance wise, can I avoid the second query? I mean I could just filter the active ones in python.. since they are subset of the original query. Though I only need to count the active ones, so would it be better to call .count istead of |length ?